# macOS keeps asking for disk password: how to allow a user to unlock File Vault encrypted disk?

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra, filevault

After a restore, macOS still requires the *disk password*. Here what happened:

First, I used `diskutil` to format my disk as *APFS encrypted* and I set a disk password. Then, I installed macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) and restored a TimeMachine backup.

The restore succeed, but something went wrong with disk decryption permissions: now at boot the macOS ask for the *disk password* (that i know), and afterwards for the *user password* for my user called `john`.

The only allowed user to decrypt the disk is a Disk user.

```
# diskutil apfs listcryptousers /dev/disk1s1
Cryptographic user for disk1s1 (1 found)
|
+-- 2FFF91FA-12A5-3F55-8252-85AAF1188EBA
Type: Disk User
```

and

```
# sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus john
2018-08-20 20:40:55.784 sysadminctl[3561:141251] Secure token is DISABLED for user John X.
```

Is there a way to allow the existing admin user `john` to unlock the disk?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to solve this would be to decrypt your disk and then encrypt it using the Filevault settings page.